# Cinemachine in unity 2022.1 weird errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I am using cinemachine to make a camera that follows the player in a 2D top-down game. The problem is that pieces of the background disappear and reappear when the player moves, and some of the outlines of objects seem to render late in comparison to the rest of the level. Below is a link to the video showing the error. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.
https://youtu.be/BiEojQQGFn8

Comment: This likely has nothing to do with Cinemachine.   How are you handling the sort order of the items under that "Grid" object?  Are they Sprite Renderers and, if so, do they have different Z values? Or are they UI images on a Canvas and, if so, do they have any sort orders setup?

Comment: Thanks, that has solved the problem of them not showing on the screen, turns out they where all in the same position in the order. This has made a stranger problem where the part of the tilemap they are on appears to move with the player, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: New problem needs a new question ;]